# Python list scope

Tags: python

Let's examine this.

```
class SomeObject:

    testList = []

    def setList(self, data):
        self.testList = data

    def getList(self):
        return self.testList

class UtilClass:

    def populateList(self, foreign, str):

        data = []
        data.append(str)

        foreign.setList(data)


def main():

    data = SomeObject()
    data2 = SomeObject()
    util = UtilClass()

    util.populateList(data, "Test 1")
    util.populateList(data2, "Test 2")
    util.populateList(data, "Test 3")


    print(data.getList())
    print(data2.getList())

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

What does the `data` object inside of `main` now contain, a copy of a the list constructed inside of `populateList()` or a reference to it?

Should I do something like `list()` or `copy.copy()` or `copy.deepcopy()`? The data object should go out of scope inside of `populateList`, right?

What happens when I pass another list to the `util` object? Does the list in`data` get altered or overwritten?

If the `data` inside of `populateList` go out of scope, why is it valid after the second call to `populateList`?

Comment: A reference to it. Only if you use `copy()` or `deepcopy()` it will construct a copy.

Comment: In Python, only variables have scope - values do not, they continue existing for as long as anything has a reference to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does the `data` object inside of main now contain, a copy of a the list constructed inside of `populateList()` or a reference to it?

A **reference** to it. But since you do not pass the reference to another object. `data` is the only one that has a reference to that list.

> Should I do something like list() or copy.copy() or copy.deepcopy()? The data object should go out of scope inside of populateList, right?

No, only if you want to **construct a copy** (for instance if you want to alter the list further later). The object will not be garbage collected because **it is allocated on the heap**. As long as there is one active variable that references it, it will stay alive.

> What happens when I pass another list to the `util` object? Does the list indata get altered or overwritten?

No, **`util` will no reference to the new list**, the old list lives independently. If no other object referenced to the old list, the old list will eventually get garbage collected.

> If the data inside of populateList go out of scope, why is it valid after the second call to `populateList`?

With *out of scope* programmers say that the list no longer listens to the `data` *identifier*. But the list still lives into memory. If other objects reference to it, they can alter/modify it, etc.

Comment: So i can safely do `setList` and not worry about it?

Comment: @Gala: yes. Python itself has to manage how it deals with objects in memory. But as long as one active variable references to an object. The object is guaranteed to stay alive.

Comment: Thanks for the info! :)